# When to prime the AppEngine Memcache with Datastore data?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, memcached, google-cloud-datastore, apache-beam

I have about 150000 records in a Google Cloud Datastore. This is a document database and it's best to use something called "Dataflow" to interact with it. Took a while to even figure that out! This is what I had to use in order to import the 150000 records into Datastore.

Now I want to "prime the memcache" and get all (or as many as possible) of those into the AppEngine memcache. Has anybody out there done this before, and if you did, what's the best way to do this? Are there any "gotchas" involved?

Comment: too broad. show us your research and alternatives you are considering. answer fully depends on many details you have not specified, like how you expect to access the data, how often it changes, what's wrong with cache on demand, etc

Comment: Unless you're using dedicated memcache, please don't do this. Haivng lots of people do this causes a 'tragedy of the commons' in shared memcache, making it worse for everyone.